High-performance liquid chromatography (HPLC) injection
While practicing with high-performance liquid chromatography (HPLC), my lecturer asked me to inject the syringe slowly into six-port valve. She briefly explained that fast injection is disadvantageous because of fluid dynamic problems.
After searching the Internet, I found several things about the fluid movement in narrow tube, but still no conclusion could be made for the disadvantage that she mentioned. Any idea?
